# d3 drag and drop v7 is always throwing errors

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I am trying to enable drag and drop in d3 forced layout, below is what I have:

```
const nodeElements = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(this.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("fill", this.getNodeColor.bind(this))


const drag = d3.drag()
  .on("start", this.dragStarted.bind(this))
  .on("drag", this.dragged.bind(this) )
  .on("end", this.dragended.bind(this));
nodeElements.call(drag);
```

But I saw this error in the page:

TS2345: Argument of type 'DragBehavior<Element, unknown, unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type....

my d3 version is v7

So, in d3 v7, what is the proper way to enable the drag and drop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that event listeners should generally be functions. Thus, you *might* try

```
d3.drag()
  .on("start", () => this.dragStarted.bind(this))
```

It's hard to say for sure since we don't know what `dragStarted` looks like.

Here's an example of a very simple application of `d3.drag` to move a circle:

```js
let w = 500
let h = 300
let svg = d3.select('#container')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h)
 
let c = svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', w/2)
  .attr('cy', h/2)
  .attr('r', 8)
  .attr('fill', 'black')
  
c.call(
  d3.drag().on("drag", function (evt) {
    c.attr("cx", evt.x).attr("cy", evt.y);
  })
)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```